# Poor out of time performance

Tags: predictive-models, panel-data, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes, out-of-sample

I am working on a behavioral model which predicts the probability of default (PD) during the next 12 months for an existing customer with an outstanding loan. My dataset consists of monthly snapshots of customers including their payment behavior based on which we want to predict the future payment behavior. The dataset is highly imbalanced (2% bad rate).
I have selected the first 6 months of year 2018 for train/test samples and the last 4 months of 2018 for out of time period. My model performance (XGBoost model and scale_pos_weight used for the imbalanced dataset) on train and test is comparable is good enough; however, the out of time performance drops significantly and the model assigns low PD to almost half of the bad observations in out of time population.
Clearly, there is a time factor that is affecting the results, but I have included the months on book as a variable. What do you recommend to improve the out of time performance?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue and have been researching for an answer. So far I have not reached an answer, but some of the hypotheses I am exploring are overfitting due to small dataset with too many features, overfitting due to hyperparameter tuning. I am exploring the option of tuning hyperparameters using an OS test set and then validating on another (different) OS test set. This way hoping to avoid overfitting due to parameter tuning. Still exploring but will share once I reach a solution.

Comment: One potential pitfall: when you have panel data, you have multiple observations on each individual at different times. I would be careful to put an individual entirely in training set or entirely in test set; don't have an individual straddling both sides. Otherwise your test performance can look good even if the algorithm is just memorizing individuals in training.

Comment: @Paul Do you think multiple years of data (2016-2018 instead of 2018) and sampling from that pool and shrinking it to say 9 months of data would hedge that pitfall? That's what I recently tried and got good results in my most recent OOT data (Q1-2021).